# EditText - Accept numbers only in multiple of 0.5 [ Eg. 0.5 , 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3 and so on]

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to have restriction on EditText to accept numbers only in multiple of 0.5 [ Eg. 0.5 , 1,  1.5, 2, 2.5, 3 and so on]. Please help

Comment: Please add the relevant Java/XML layout code.

Comment: override `onTextChanged` and check user input as you want

Comment: You can use a spinner and put possible numbers in an Arraylist that user just can choose one of them.

Answer (score 0):

My first answer to the question

override `onTextChanged`

You can try to use regular expression to validate

```
/^[+]?\d+(\.5+([0]*)?)?$/
```

Answer (score 0):

U can did it only form MainActivity.class :

```
          if(Integer.parseInt(edittext.getText().toString)%.5==0){

                /////

            }else{

                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ".5 multiple required", 
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            edittext.setText("");

            }
```